# Parcel Bundler Doesn't Add Content Hash

Tags: node.js, express, parceljs

My code is:

```
const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler');
const path = require('path');
const options = {
    contentHash: true,
    minify: true
};

(async function() {
    const bundler = new Bundler(path.join(__dirname, '../sass/main.scss'), options);
    await bundler.bundle();
})();
```

Output is just `main.css` and `main.js` in `./dist` directory, but there is no hash on the file name. Why is `contentHash: true` not working?

Thanks.

Comment: The docs say 'Entrypoints are never hashed' - could that be the reason? See here: https://en.parceljs.org/production.html#file-naming-strategy